# Custom Node Configuration in AKS using Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, swapfile, virtual-machine-scale-set

I wanted to create noodpool with swap memory enabled in AKS, I have gone through
Terraform documentation there I can see `swap_file_size_mb` and `vm_swappiness` are the only thing related to [swap](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster). My question is

1. is there any way to use this flag --fail-swap-on
   to false(or it will automatically set to false when we set `swap_file_size_mb`)
2. And is there any way to change MemorySwap.SwapBehavior to "UnlimitedSwap"

Are these things are possible in AKS, or Am I missing something, I want a working node
that has swap memory and should use for workload through terraform. Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is a kubelet_config block in AKS schema that allows settings failSwapOn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/custom-node-configuration#virtual-memory

but that one is not exposed in terraform, but i think its hardcoded to false: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/ddd6a9e2ef99f2e859b567badbed1aa829261caa/internal/services/containers/kubernetes_cluster_node_pool_resource.go#L1020

2. MemorySwap - i dont think so, at least I dont see it in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/custom-node-configuration#virtual-memory

Comment: Thank, looks like no support from AKS for MemorySwap. for now maybe.